# Email Signature HTML file on FTP Server

Tags: html

I have created a HMTL signature that will be saved on the FTP domain server, however, the problem arises when I try to create a HMTL file that will be saved in the ‘Microsoft\signatures\’ folder located in the appdata on each local PC, so when they create an email it pulls through the individual signatures stored on the domain.

I've tried the following;

```
<a href="http://www.#############.com/uploads/images/o/Email%20Signature.html"></a>

<script src="http://www.#############.com/uploads/images/o/Email%20Signature.html"></script>
```

Then end result in outlook is a blank signature.

Please help!!

Comment: Which problem arises?

Comment: The first line is a link without any link text to click on, so you don't see anything. The second line is to load a javascript file (or any other kind of script), but you are referencing a HTML file. Keep in mind that HTML is not a programming language and loading external data from a HTML email in your email client is usually disabled for security reasons. What are you trying to do and why do you not place the signature directly into the email?